# Android - How to replace Hilt's @Inject contructor annotated classes with a fake class in tests

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-hilt, mockk

I learned about @UnunstallModules, which is really nice. But what if I do not have a module and the class is just annotated with @Inject?

For example, I have a Authentication class

```kotlin
@Singleton
class AuthenticationRepo @Inject constructor(
    @ApplicationContext appContext: Context
) {

    fun login(): Response {
       // some stuff
    }

    suspend fun connect(url: String) {
        // blah
    }
}
```

It is injected into a ViewModel, which will trigger it. The test looks like this:

```kotlin
@HiltAndroidTest
class JellyFinRepoTest {

    @BindValue
    val auth: AuthenticationRepo = mockk()

    @Test
    fun bla2h() {

        every { auth.login() } returns defaultResponse()
        val activity = launchActivity<MainActivity>()



        Thread.sleep(100000)
    }
}
```

But when Actvity shows up on device then it crashes with

```
05-29 23:20:02.625  1880 20749 W Binder  : Outgoing transactions from this process must be FLAG_ONEWAY
05-29 23:20:02.625  1880 20749 W Binder  : java.lang.Throwable
05-29 23:20:02.625  1880 20749 W Binder  :  at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:1114)
05-29 23:20:02.625  1880 20749 W Binder  :  at android.app.IInstrumentationWatcher$Stub$Proxy.instrumentationFinished(IInstrumentationWatcher.java:164)
05-29 23:20:02.625  1880 20749 W Binder  :  at com.android.server.am.InstrumentationReporter$MyThread.run(InstrumentationReporter.java:86)
```

Comment: I recently come across the same scenario. Have you found the solution?

Comment: What does `AuthenticationRepo` do? Does it make API calls? Do you want to mock response?

Answer (score 0):

As you use Hilt; I will explain you with Hilt.

You created an AuthenticationRepo class like this.

```
@Singleton
class AuthenticationRepoImpl @Inject constructor(
    @ApplicationContext appContext: Context
) : AuthenticationRepo {

     override fun login(): Response {
        // some stuff
     }

     override suspend fun connect(url: String) {
        // blah
     }
}
```

You need an interface class to use the polymorphism feature to test a fake class too(Note that the polymorphism is not for the test, We use it to test our fake class).

```
interface AuthenticationRepo {
    fun login(): Response 

    suspend fun connect(url: String)
}
```

Then you should provide it in a class like AppModule: like this:

```
@InstallIn(ApplicationComponent::class)
@Module()
class AppModule {
    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideAuthenticationRepoImpl(
       @ApplicationContext appContext: Context
    ) = AuthenticationRepoImpl(appContext) as AuthenticationRepo
}
```

Now in your viewModel use AuthenticationRepo in your constructor.
1: It will be loosely coupled
2: It will be tested by the fake class

```
@HiltViewModel
class AuthenticationViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val repository: AuthenticationRepo
) : ViewModel() {
   // TODO
}
```

For testing this viewModel, you can create AuthenticationRepoFake by implementing the AuthenticationRepo interface and creating your fake objects.

In your test class create your AuthenticationViewModel and AuthenticationRepoFake then pass your fake class to viewModel and do you tests.

Comment: Thanks for reply but this is something else. You have added a new interface and a new module, which is what I do not want to have... maybe my question was missing some details, will update it and let you know

Comment: I guess having an interface and a module is the only way to mock objects with @UninstallModule... 

My wish is to avoid creating Fake classes and somehow replace classes Hilt has in its graph with mockk's mocked classes.  How do you write tests? Do you create fake classes of every repo?